# How to fix hive code for counting a column and group by another column?

Tags: hadoop, hive, group-by

There are 3 columns in my hive data (`user, gender, rating`). now, I want to count number of `user_id, gender` wise. I have written hive code as

```
select user_id, gender, count(*) from u_user group by user_id;
```

but the error that I have got is

> SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:16 Expression not in GROUP BY
>   key 'gender'

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the keys you `group by` should be the same with the keys in the `select`. As below:

```
select user_id,gender,count(1) from u_user group by user_id,gender;
```

And if you want to count user_id of each gender type , you can write like this:

```
select gender,count(distinct user_id) from u_user group by gender;
```